# Why write a layout in config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a module. In config.xml i found this code:

```
 <frontend>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <subscription>
                        <file>MailChimp_Subscription.xml</file>
                    </subscription>
                </updates>
            </layout>
    </frontend>
```

Why we must write it? What I should do, if I want use this module in other layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout XML

Layout XML files can be found in app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout. Each Magento module may define its own layout XML file in the config.xml file.

```
<frontend>
  <layout>
    <updates>
      <mymodule>
        <file>mymodule.xml</file>
      </mymodule>
    </updates>
  </layout>
</frontend>
```

Before the page is rendered, `Magento loads all configured layout update files and its design updates` to determine which block is to be rendered at which location.

source : [Complete example on layout](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/)

To know in deep read [Layout Update](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html)
If you are creataing template lets say for home page or checkout page than in `we define the layouts in our moudle layout file like`/var/www/html/psydro16/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mymodule.xml`

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
..............
  <reference name="bottom.container">
     <block type="mymodule/mymoduletemplate" name="mymodule_mymoduletemplate" template="reviews/mymoduletemplate.phtml" />
..................
 <cms_index_index>
```

This way we call our module template in that layout.

Comment: Ok, but if i wanna use this module in other layout?

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич i updated my suggestion, is that solves your concern

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич If it help , you can mark the answer or we will try to update the answer so that it help other community member to follow the right suggestion.

Comment: @inrasaurabh ty , it help